# Использование персонального соединения с БД

Tags: база-данных

Допустим есть сайт, имеющий подключение к базе данных для получения данных. Как правило для этого используется один пользователь базы данных для всех пользователей сайта.

Теперь представьте, что каждый пользователь при авторизации на сайте, подключается со своим логином и паролем к базе.

Повлияет ли работа базы данных в таком режиме на данные и их целостность? Ну и вообще есть ли какие-либо подводные камни?

Comment: А для какой цели это предполагается использовать ? Плюсов особо не заметно. При том что установка соединения с БД под конкретным пользователем усложняет систему, приходится вести пользователей средствами БД. Хранить где то на сервере логины/пароли потому как web-сессия короткоживущая, а передавать логин и пароль при каждом обращении с клиента как то не принято (из соображений безопасности)

Comment: Сгенерировав (а ещё лучше - прежде чем сгенерировать) идею, надо первым делом ответить, зачем это. Какие мы желаем получить профиты и какие при этом ожидаем проблемы. Ну глупо же сперва сделать, а потом придумывать, зачем это было сделано, правда? Ну ладно, пусть про проблемы потом... но вот очень бы хотелось услышать от Вас, чего Вы ждёте от реализации этой идеи - каждому юзеру своя учётная запись на сервере БД.

Comment: @Akina, проблема не в том чего я жду. Я уже знаю какие профиты это принесёт. Вопрос в по большей части в целостности данных. Например, при одном пользователе БД всё нормально, а при двух - вот такие проблемы с данными могут возникнуть

Comment: @Mike, ну так есть всякие службы централизованной идентификации и авторизации пользователей. Забыл упомянуть, что сайт находится во внутренней сети и пользователи заходят через LDAP. Сайт работает через LDAP

Comment: @ArchDemon Нет, с этой стороны проблем не ждите. Ну если  не считать того, что чем больше учёток создаётся, тем больше вероятность накосячить.

Comment: На целостность это никак не скажется. Для БД пользователь интересен только с точки зрения проверки прав доступа. Если права на объект есть дальше работают общие механизмы никак от выбранного пользователя не зависящие

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые СУБД, такие как MS SQL распространяются с разной ценой в зависимости от одновременных соединений к БД => чем больше одновременных соединений, тем выше стоимость лицензии.

Так же если каждый пользователь будет иметь прямой доступ к БД на чтение и изменение, то возможны всякие коллизии, когда один пользователь прочитал одни данные, а другой пользователь изменяет эти данные. Ну это уже смотря, как будет архитектурно организовано все.

ИМХО: Я думаю, что если доступ к данным организуется централизованно какой-то службой, а не каждый пользователь напрямую, то так меньше проблем.

Comment: С ценой проблем нету т.к. используется не MS SQL. А при одном пользователе к БД коллизии что вы провели отсутствуют? Мне как раз этот момент больше всего интересует.

Comment: Какая разница под одним или под разными пользователями открыты две изолированные транзакции?